# Not enough space to display Admob ad error

Tags: android, admob

It is not a new error but none of the online answers look to me more approprite, Kindly help me in this problem.
I have incorporated Admob in my application. It is working on some Screens perfectly but on other it is not working. When I looked on the log it says.

```
Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <464, 762>
```

I want to know that is there an easy way to display ads on all screens sizes and avoid such errors.

My XML code is as follows.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

I have provided permissions of Internet and Access network state.

Answer (score 8):

Any chance you have an 8dp margin/padding on each side of your main layout?  The AdView needs the entire width of the screen (in portrait) to be able to display the ad, but it only has 464dp of width space.

Answer (score 3):

try:

`android:layout_width="480dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

or

`android:layout_width="480dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is on the line

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

the layout container is not big enought to contain the adview. Try to set it to:
 `android:layout_width="320dp"` , this will ask an ad with a different (smaller) size.

Answer (score 0):

```
here i give a sample example code. you can follow.
step 1:

design your activity layout like this
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
             android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:background="#2d2f2f"
            ads:adUnitId="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
</LinearLayout>
step 2:
follow this code in activity
 final AdView adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
                //re.setTesting(true);
                adview.loadAd(re);
            }
        });     

step 3:
add permission in application manifest
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

also add admob activity in manifest
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```